# Why do my bluetooth devices stop working on my MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, bluetooth

I have this intermittent problem with Bluetooth devices on my MacBook Pro.

Even with a fresh set of batteries, occasionally my MacBook pro just seems to "lose" one or the other of them.  The Bluetooth preferences says they are still connected, but the computer is not processing any input from them.  If I disconnect a malfunctioning device from the preferences tab and reconnect from the preferences tab it always starts working, but if I turn the device off and back on it never starts working.

Comment: Happens to me too, Apple bluetooth keyboard input stops being accepted, even though it is still "connected". This happens with most of our office (we all have MBP+Apple wireless keyboards).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue that has been fixed in [OS X 10.5.8](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3606).

> Improves overall Bluetooth reliability with external devices, USB webcams and printers.

Answer (score 1):

I have this happen with my Mighty Mouse occasionally.  My suspicion is that there's a bug in Apple's Bluetooth daemon (at least in OS X 10.5, because it didn't happen in 10.4).  Turning off Bluetooth and then turning it back on again seems to get it back to normal (until the next occurrence).